# How to iterate only through unique combinations of multiple objects?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, loops, hash

The title is a bit of a doozy.

I'm working on a project where users can make bids. The resulting items can be won exclusively or split between up to 3 users. One user can put in an exclusive bet of $20, and another 3 users can both agree to do a 3-way split and each only pay $10, resulting in $30, beating the first bidder.

I need to run through a list of possibly a dozen different bidders who agreed to the 3-way split to determine the winning trio:

```
Rza                              => $20 # loses
ODB + Gza                        => $25 # loses
InspectahDeck + Ghostface + ODB  => $50 # wins
```

Alternatively

```
Rza                              => $100,000 # wins
ODB + Gza                        => $25 # loses
InspectahDeck + Ghostface + ODB  => $50 # loses
```

All I have is an array of `Bid` objects, belonging to a variety of users. My goal is to see all possible combinations of up those who wish to split with others and see who comes out on top.

I tried to do something like:

```
bids.each do |bid1|
 bids.each do |bid2|
  bids.each do |bid3|
  # Fill a hash here, but only if the permutation of the bids is unique
  end
 end
end
```

I'm having a hard time with this since it seems horribly inefficient and has tons of duplicates, sometimes same bids appearing twice. I'd like some help or at tips to point me in the right direction.

I'm really stumped.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Another tricky detail: Each bidder can have multiple bids set. So the same guy can have 1 exclusive, 1 2-way and 1 3-way.

Comment: What does each individual `Bid` object look like?  What are its attributes?  Also, you have a typo here: "My goal is to see all possible combinations **of up those** who wish to split with others and see who comes out on top."  Not sure what you meant there.

Comment: Sort the bids array according to the bid price, choose the first 3 users that agreed to split the costs, pick the sum price (1). Choose the first user that doesn't want to split the cost, pick his/her bid price (2). The higher of (1), (2) wins the bid. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ArieShaw that's exactly the kind of out of the box thinking I needed. Let me try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have something like this:

```
class Bid
  attr_accessor :user   # link to the user
  attr_accessor :price  # dollar amount
  attr_accessor :way    # 1 means 1-way, 2 means 2-way, 3 means 3-way
end
```

Get the highest bets of each kind:

```
best_1_way  = bids.select{|bid| bid.way == 1}.max
best_2_ways = bids.select{|bid| bid.way == 2}.sort[-2,2]
best_3_ways = bids.select{|bid| bid.way == 3}.sort[-3,3]
```

Get the total prices:

```
total_1_way_price = best_1_way.price
total_2_ways_price = best_2_ways.map(&:price).inject(&:+)
total_3_ways_price = best_3_ways.map(&:price).inject(&:+)
```

Compare these three items, and you get your winner.

If you have a lot of bids and want to optimize:

```
all_1_ways, all_2_ways, all_3_ways = 
  bids.group_by{|bid| bid.way }.values_at(1,2,3)
```